# How to assert Map contains Map with entry

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have a unit test that needs to check for a nested map value.  I can get my assertion to work by pulling out the entry and matching the underlying `Map`, but I was looking for a clear way to show what the assertion is doing.  Here is a very simplified test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MapContainsMapTest {
    @Test
    public void testMapHasMap() {
        Map<String, Object> outerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> nestedMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        nestedMap.put("foo", "bar");
        outerMap.put("nested", nestedMap);

        // works but murky
        assertThat((Map<String, Object>) outerMap.get("nested"), hasEntry("foo", "bar"));
        // fails but clear
        assertThat(outerMap, hasEntry("nested", hasEntry("foo", "bar")));
    }
}
```

It seems the problem is the outer map is being compared using `hasEntry(K key, V value)` while what I want to use is `hasEntry(Matcher<? super K> keyMatcher, Matcher<? super V> valueMatcher)`.  I am not sure how to coerce the assertion to use the second form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_It seems the problem is the outer map is being compared using ..._" `hasEntry(is("key"), is("value"))` for example would cause the second form to be used. Maybe you could use `equalTo` matcher in place of `is`, but either way, the readability goes out of the window.

Comment: The problem is with the outer test, so I need something like `equalTo("nested")...` but that doesn't work unless I change the outer map type to `Map<String, Map<String,Object>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably extend a new Matcher for that, something like that (beware, NPEs lurking):

```
class SubMapMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Map<?,?>> {

private Object key;
private Object subMapKey;
private Object subMapValue;

public SubMapMatcher(Object key, Object subMapKey, Object subMapValue) {
    super();
    this.key = key;
    this.subMapKey = subMapKey;
    this.subMapValue = subMapValue;
}

@Override
public boolean matches(Object item) {

    Map<?,?> map = (Map<?,?>)item;

    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        return false;
    }

    Object o = map.get(key);

    if (!(o instanceof Map<?,?>)) {
        return false;
    }

    Map<?,?> subMap = (Map<?,?>)o;
    return subMap.containsKey(subMapKey) && subMap.get(subMapKey).equals(subMapValue);
}

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText(String.format("contains %s -> %s : %s", key, subMapKey, subMapValue));
}

public static SubMapMatcher containsSubMapWithKeyValue(String key, String subMapKey, String subMapValue) {
    return new SubMapMatcher(key, subMapKey, subMapValue);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer works.  However, I think I would like to see if I can extend this to allow any level of nesting.

Comment: Sounds easy enough, you can simple use a signature like `Object value, String... keys`. Then iterate through the keys, get the submap until you reach last one (or stumble upon a null or not-map as your value) and check the value. For example `containsValueInSubMap( someValue, map0Key, map1Key, map2Key);` Of course, personally I would NOT suggest using a standard Map for a key -> "value OR submap" mapping, but instead something more specific which would also allow have generic value types (a map with submaps and values is effectively a tree, should be easy to find something).

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to put `Map<String, Object>` as values in your `outerMap` adjust the declaration accordingly. Then you can do

```
@Test
public void testMapHasMap() {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> nestedMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    nestedMap.put("foo", "bar");
    outerMap.put("nested", nestedMap);

    Object value = "bar";
    assertThat(outerMap, hasEntry(equalTo("nested"), hasEntry("foo", value)));  
}
```

`Object value = "bar";` is necessary for compile reasons. Alternatively you could use

```
assertThat(outerMap,
   hasEntry(equalTo("nested"), Matchers.<String, Object> hasEntry("foo", "bar")));
```

Comment: My example is a simplified version of my test in which the outerMap is a JSON object where not all the entries are maps, so I must keep the map declaration as written.

Answer (score 5):

If You declare outerMap as `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` you don't need the ugly cast. Like this:

```
public class MapContainsMapTest {

    @Test
    public void testMapHasMap() {
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
        nestedMap.put("foo", "bar");
        outerMap.put("nested", nestedMap);

        assertThat(outerMap.get("nested"), hasEntry("foo", "bar"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanGetz if I remove the cast, it doesnt compile,  outerMap must be declared as Map<String, Map<String, Object>>.

Comment: My example is a simplified version of my test in which the outerMap is a JSON object where not all the entries are maps, so I must keep the map declaration as written.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
        assertThat(nestedMap).contains(Map.entry("foo", "bar"));
        assertThat(outerMap).contains(Map.entry("nested", nestedMap));
```